# What are the consequences of converting heap-indexes to clustered indexes on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, clustered-index

I've recently got the advice, that I should convert all our tables from using heap indexes such that each table has a clustered index. **What are the consequences** of persuing this strategy? E.g. is it more important to regularly reorganize the database? datagrowth? danger of really slow inserts? Danger of page-defragmentation if the PK is a GUID? *Noticable speed-increase of my application?* **What are your experiences?**

To serve as inspiration for good answers, here are some of the "facts" I've picked up from other threads here on stackoverflow

1. Almost certainly want to establish a clustered index on every table in your database. If a table does not have one. Performance of most common queries is better.
2. Clustered indexes are not always bad on GUIDs... it all depends upon the needs of your  application. The INSERT speed will  suffer, but the SELECT speed will be improved.
3. The problem with clustered indexes in a GUID field are that the GUIDs are random, so when a new record is inserted, a significant portion of the data on disk has to be moved to insert the records into the middle of the table.
4. Clustered index on GUID is ok in situations where the GUID has a meaning and improves performance by placing related data close to each other http://randommadness.blogspot.com/2008/07/guids-and-clustered-indexes.html
5. Clustering doesn't affect lookup speed - a unique non-clustered index should do the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your key is a GUID, then a non-clustered index on it is probably just as effective as a clustered index on it. This is because on GUIDs you absolutely never ever can have range scans on them (what could `between 'b4e8e994-c315-49c5-bbc1-f0e1b000ad7c' and '3cd22676-dffe-4152-9aef-54a6a18d32ac'` possibly mean??). With a width of 16 bytes, a GUID clustered index key is wider than a row id that you'd get from a heap, so a NC index on a PK guid is actually strategy that can be defended in a discussion.

But making the primary key the clustered index key is *not* the only way to build a clustered index over your heap. Do you have *other* frequent queries that request ranges over a certain column? Typical candidates are columns like `date`, `state` or `deleted`. If you do, then you should consider making those columns the clustered index key (it does *not* have to be unique) because doing so may help queries that request ranges, like 'all records from yesterday'.

The only scenario where heaps have significant performance benefit is inserts, specially bulk inserts. IF your load is not insert heavy, then you should definitely go for a clustered index. See [Clustered Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639.aspx).

Going over over your points:

> Almost certainly want to establish a clustered index on every table in
>   your database. If a table does not
>   have one. Performance of most common
>   queries is better.

A clustered index that can satisfy range requirements for most queries will dramatically improve performance, true. A clustered index that can satisfy order requirements can be helpful too, but nowhere as helpful as one that can satisfy a range.

> Clustered indexes are not always bad on GUIDs... it all depends upon
>   the needs of your application. The
>   INSERT speed will suffer, but the
>   SELECT speed will be improved.

Only probe SELECTs will be improved: `SELECT ... WHERE key='someguid';`. Queries by object ID and Foreign key lookups will benefit from this clustered index. A NC index can server the same purpose just as well.

> The problem with clustered indexes in a GUID field are that the GUIDs are
>   random, so when a new record is
>   inserted, a significant portion of the
>   data on disk has to be moved to insert
>   the records into the middle of the
>   table.

Wrong. Insert into position in an index does *not* have to move data. The worst it can happen is a page-split. A Page-split is (somehow) expensive, but is not the end of the world. You comment suggest that *all* data (or at least a 'significant' part) has to be moved to make room for the new row, this is nowhere near true.

> Clustered index on GUID is ok in situations where the GUID has a
>   meaning and improves performance by
>   placing related data close to each
>   other
>   http://randommadness.blogspot.com/2008/07/guids-and-clustered-indexes.html

I can't possibly imagine a scenario where GUID can have 'related data'. A GUID is the quintessential random structure how could two random GUIDs relate in *any* way? The scenario Donald gives has a better solution: [Resolving PAGELATCH Contention on Highly Concurrent INSERT Workloads](http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2009/09/22/resolving-pagelatch-contention-on-highly-concurrent-insert-workloads-part-1.aspx), which is cheaper to implement (less storage required) and works for unique keys too (the solution in linked article would not work for unique keys, only for foreign keys).

> Clustering doesn't affect lookup speed - a unique non-clustered index
>   should do the job.

For probes (lookup a specific unique key) yes. A NC index is *almost* as fast as the clustered index (the NC index lookup *does* require and additional key lookup to fetch in the rest of the columns). Where clustered index shines is range scans, as it the clustered index can *cover* any query, while a NC index that *could* potentially satisfy the same range may loose on the *coverage* and trigger the [Index Tipping Point](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/The-Tipping-Point.aspx).

Comment: Are Clustered indexes not also more efficient for regular non-range scan queries? I mean, an indirection is skipped. Would you recon we'd feel any difference in performance?

Comment: Is seldom that I've seen the extra indirection play any significant role in perf. A much higher danger is in deadlocks, as described here: http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend you read Kimberly Tripp's [The Clustered Index Debate Continues...](http://sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx) in which she details quite clearly all the benefits of having a **good* clustering key over having a heap.

Pretty much all operations are faster - **yes!** even inserts and updates!

But this requires a **good** clustering key, and a GUID with its very random and unpredictable nature is not considered a good candidate for a clustering key. GUIDs as clustering key are bad - whether they have application meaning or not - just avoid those.

Your best bet is a key which is narrow, stable, unique and ever-increasing - a column of type `INT IDENTITY` fulfills all those requirements ideally.

For a lot more background on why a GUID doesn't make a good clustering key, and on just how bad it is, see more of Kim Tripp's blog posts:

- [GUIDs as PRIMARY key and/or clustering key](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/GUIDs-as-PRIMARY-KEYs-andor-the-clustering-key.aspx)
- [Disk space is cheap... but that's **not** the point!](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/post/Disk-space-is-cheap.aspx)

Comment: yes I should have referenced Kimberlys post above. But what are your real-life experiences on the subject? Have you also noticed speedier apps when turning over to CI?

Comment: @Carlo V. Dango: yes, I changed the CI from GUID's to INT IDENTITY and had a very noticeable speed increase. Plus the speed doesn't degrade as quickly, either. Getting away from a bad CI certainly helps!

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend the book "SQL Performance Explained" - it is a 200 page book about indexes.

It also mentions when clustered indexes have worse performance than normal indexs. One of the problems is that the clustered index itself is a B-tree. So when you have other indexes on the same table, they can't point to a specifik row - instead they point to a "key" in the clustered index, so "the way" to the data gets longer.